# Who do you think you are that you should...?

Tags: subjunctives, complementation

What's the function of "that" in the following sentences? How do you analyze it?

> Who do you think you are **that** you should talk to me like that?

> Who are you **that** you should talk to me like that?

It's not a relative pronoun. What is its definition in the dictionary?

Comment: Have you done any research, like looking "that" up in a dictionary and seeing if any of the definitions fit your example sentences?

Comment: Apparently, it's not a relative pronoun. This use seems rare.

Comment: Adding your research along with the specific point you're confused about would help prevent this question from getting closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Who do you think you are *that* you should talk to me like that?

> Who are you *that* you should talk to me like that?

This is an archaic or literary usage.  What we would actually say is "Who are you to talk to me like that?" or (colloquially) "Who do you think you are, talking to me like that?".  Alternatively we might say "What gives you the right to talk to me like that?" or "Who do you think you are? How dare you talk to me like that?".

In any case, in your sentences, **that** is a subordinating conjunction.

In the Oxford English Dictionary, under **that**, I. 4. c.:

> Introducing a clause expressing a fact (with vb. in indic.), or a supposition (with vb. in subj.), as a consequence attributed to the cause indicated by the principal clause (which is most commonly interrogative): sometimes nearly = in consequence of which; or (with indic.) = since, seeing that.

The citations include:

- 1611   Bible (King James) Isa. liii. 2   There is no beautie that we should desire him.
- a1616   Shakespeare Two Gentlemen of Verona (1623) iv. ii. 39   Who is Siluia? what is she? That all our Swaines commend her?
- 1787   W. Cowper Stanzas Yearly Bill Mortality 8   Did famine or did plague prevail, That so much death appears?
- 1842   Tennyson Lady Clare in Poems (new ed.) II. 196   Are ye out of your mind, ...that ye speak so wild?

The following in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/that) is slightly less specific but arguably covers the same ground (sense 2.a.(3)):

> used as a function word to introduce a subordinate clause expressing consequence, result, or effect.  *are of sufficient importance that they cannot be neglected*

Comment: What is its definition in the dictionary?

Comment: I have edited my answer.